# Java Image Drawing

Tags: java, 2d-games

I'm in the process of making a simple 2-D game, however I am having trouble drawing images. Below are a few classes that are relevant to the problem

```
private Vector<Bullet> ammo = new Vector<Bullet>(100);

public class Bullet{
    Image img;
    int x, y, speed;
    boolean show;
    Bullet(Image img,int x, int y, int speed, boolean show){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img = img;
        this.show = show;
    }
    public void draw(ImageObserver obs) {
        if(show)
            g2.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, obs);
    }
    public void update(){
        this.y -= 1;
    }
}

public class Movement{
    ....

    Movement(....){
        .....
    }

    public void fly(){
        ......

        ammo.add(new Bullet(bullet1, m.x, m.y, 7, true));
   }



public class MyPlane {

    KeyControl key;
    Movement flight;
    Image img;
    int x, y, speed, move = 0;
    int boom;
    ...
}


public void drawDemo() {   
    ...        
        for(Bullet bullets: ammo)
            bullets.update();
    ...
        for(Bullet bullets: ammo)
            bullets.draw(this);
    }
}
```

When I call bullets.draw(this) nothing actually is drawn on the screen. I know however that the ammo vector does contain the correct information, such as the x coordinate, y coordinate... I'm using Graphics 2-D by the way. Any help and or suggestions would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if(bimg == null) {
        Dimension windowSize = getSize();
        bimg = (BufferedImage) createImage(windowSize.width, 
                windowSize.height);
        g2 = bimg.createGraphics();
    }
    drawDemo();
    g.drawImage(bimg, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Comment: Where's the `g2` reference coming from?

Comment: added it to the bottom of the post

Comment: Not the best choice, you should be passing it to the "paint" class.  Also, why are you overriding paint and implementing your own double buffer?  Why aren't you calling `super.paint`?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Problem has been solved, apparently I accidentally declared the image "bullet1" twice, once as a global image, and once inside of another method meant to initialize the images. Removing the second declaration of "bullet1" has solved the issue. Thanks though!

Comment: Ahh...actually, I  think you're setting yourself up for more trouble, guess we'll be seeing more questions from you soon...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should draw the image like this:

```
public void draw(Graphics g2) {
    if(show)
        g2.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, null);
}
```

Then in your plane class you have to add **Graphics** as an argument of the drawDemo() method:

```
public void drawDemo(Graphics g2) {   
...        
    for(Bullet bullets: ammo)
        bullets.update();
...
    for(Bullet bullets: ammo)
        bullets.draw(g2);
}
```

}

and finally in you paint(Graphics g) method you call this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   /*
      ...
   */
   drawDemo(g2);
   g.drawImage(bimg, 0, 0, this);
}
```